# Date comperison doesn't work in laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

i got a problem with the comparison of 2 dates.

**What i'm trying to accomplish:**

I have a simple middleware in laravel where i check if one date is higher or lower is than the other.

code (Middleware\ifTrialExpired.php):

```
$subscription = Auth::user()->subscription;
$date = Carbon::now()->isoFormat('DD-MM-YY');

if($date > $subscription->trial_period_end && $subscription->has_trial)
{
    return redirect()->route('settings.plan.index');
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```

**What the problem is:**

In this case the 'trial_period_end' date in my database is '05-12-19', the current date is '06-11-19'. But i keeps redirecting me to the 'settings.plan.index' route, but i only want that to happen when the current date (06-11-19) is greater than the trial_period_end (05-12-19).

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: do you really think that  if("05-12-19" >  "06-11-19"){ //some code }   is going to work? if you don't count it as string then there is no data type that support something like that, make them UNIX epouch and try again strtotime($yourDate)

Comment: Well, i did try that but it doesn't work either.

Comment: `if(strtotime($date) > strtotime($subscription->trial_period_end) && $subscription->has_trial)
      {
         return redirect()->route('settings.plan.index');
      } else {
         return $next($request);
      }`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work!

Comment: @CorneliusvanErkelens Can you check `Auth::user()->subscription` return date ? Please show return result. Like `dd($subscription->trial_period_end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're comparing date-times as strings, you should *always* use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the dates, because any other format will fail as a string comparison.

However, better yet, don't use string comparisons at all.

The `Carbon` class includes comparison methods, so make everything into a Carbon object, and use them to compare.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$subscription = Auth::user()->subscription;
$dateNow = Carbon::now();

$trialEndDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $subscription->trial_period_end);

if($dateNow->gt($trialEndDate) && $subscription->has_trial)
{
    return redirect()->route('settings.plan.index');
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```

(NB: this is untested, and may need adjustment as I don't actually know what format your `trial_period_end` is stored in).

Comment: While the 'old style PHP' did work fine, i think this is cleaner! Thanks, you only need to swap the 'date' and 'format' paramters. So for me it worked like this `$trialEndDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $subscription->trial_period_end);`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped. I wrote the answer from memory without checking the params, so apologies for getting them the wrong way round; I'll fix that in the answer.
Meanwhile, it's worth pointing out that if your dates are stored in the DB in `d-m-Y` format, then your're already doing something wrong: all good databases support a DateTime datatype, and you should use that for storing dates, because if you think comparing dates is hard in PHP with funny formats, it's much worse in the database; you'll never be able to sort by that field, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Compare dates

Declare two dates

```
$date1 = "12-03-26"; 
$date2 = "2011-10-24";
```

Use strtotime() function to convert date into dateTimestamp

```
$dateTimestamp1 = strtotime($date1); 
$dateTimestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
```

Compare the timestamp date

```
if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp2) 
    echo "$date1 is latest than $date2"; 
else
    echo "$date1 is older than $date2";
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I dit that, but that doesn't work either. ```$date = strtotime(Carbon::now());
      $trialPeriodEnd = strtotime($subscription->trial_period_end);

      if($date > $trialPeriodEnd && $subscription->has_trial)
      {
         return redirect()->route('settings.plan.index');
      } else {
         return $next($request);
      }```

Comment: Just show the date which you get in `$date`,`$trialPeriodEnd`,`$subscription->has_trial`

Comment: `$date = 1163894400` `$trialPeriodEnd = 1134950400` `$subscription->has_trial` is a boolean. The weird thing is that `$date` is indeed bigger than `$trialPeriodEnd` (with `strtotime()`). But today's date is 06-11-19 and the trial_period_end is 05-12-19 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a date comparison using carbon `gt` function.:https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Try below code:

```
$subscription = Auth::user()->subscription;
$date = Carbon::now();

$sub_date  = Carbon::create($subscription->trial_period_end);   

if($date->gt($sub_date) && $subscription->has_trial)
{
    return redirect()->route('settings.plan.index');
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Nooooooo!! You've got `Carbon` why would you need to use PHP's old-style date handling functions like `strtotime()`??  :-(

Comment: @Spudley How would you do it with Carbon than?

Comment: @CorneliusvanErkelens Laravel `Carbon` facade is useful instead of using php old style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $date1 = "12-03-26"; 
 $date2 = "20-10-24"; 
 $dateTimestamp1 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date1)); 
 $dateTimestamp2 = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date2));  
 if ($dateTimestamp1 > $dateTimestamp2) 
 echo "$date1 is latest than $date2"; 
 else
 echo "$date1 is older than $date2";
```

Output will be

```
 12-03-26 is latest than 20-10-24
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Can you explain why this worked? Is it because of the iso formating i used?

Comment: The problem related to `isoFormat('DD-MM-YY')` function.use `Carbon::createFromFormat($date, 'd-m-Y')`